# Will apt-get upgrade interrupt server operation?

Tags: apt

I am running a Raspberry Pi that is providing DNS, DHCP, file sharing, and other services to my home.  I want to run `apt-get upgrade` but do not want to interrupt other users and am unsure what happens if a new package is downloaded for a running service.  I could not find detailed information about the workings of `apt-get upgrade` to determine if it restarts services or what other actions it takes during its operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgraded services are typically restarted, but not directly by `apt`, which is why you won’t find much about it there. The behaviour of each service is implemented in its package’s “maintainer scripts”, which run when a package is installed, upgraded, or removed.

On upgrade, there are two main strategies:

- stop the service at the start of the upgrade, and start it again once the upgrade is complete;
- note that the service needs to restart, and restart it once the upgrade is complete.

The latter results in less downtime, but is harder to get right (if it’s even possible), so the more common approach is the former. In both cases, there will be an interruption in service at some point. The more packages are upgraded in one go, the longer the interruption is liable to be.

In summary, you always need to consider that a package upgrade is an interruption in service, and you need to plan accordingly. In the worst case, the interruption can be lengthy — if the service fails to come back up...